# hide and show text box on click of a tr and on button click print the same in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to show text box on the row clicked by hiding the labels of the clicked row and on button click the text box data should be printed on a "showresult" Div
My problem is am not able to hide and show the textbox i have gathered a script which change the color but am not sure how to hide and show the text box and print the data.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('tr').click(function () {
        if(this.style.background == "" || this.style.background =="white") {
            $(this).css('background', 'red');
        }
        else {
            $(this).css('background', 'white');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
    <tr>
        <th>Column1</th>
        <th>Column2</th>
        <th>Column3</th>
        <th>Column4</th>
        <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td><label>data1</label> <input type="text" value="1" /></td>
        <td><label>data2</label>  <input type="text" value="2"  /></td>
        <td><label>data3</label>  <input type="text" value="3" /></td>
        <td><label>data4</label>  <input type="text" value="4" /></td>
        <td><label>data5</label>  <input type="text" value="5" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>data6</label> <input type="text" value="6" /></td>
        <td><label>data7</label>  <input type="text" value="7" /></td>
        <td><label>data8</label>  <input type="text" value="8"  /></td>
        <td><label>data9</label>  <input type="text" value="9" /></td>
        <td><label>data10</label>  <input type="text" value="10" /></td>
    </tr>

</table>

<input type="button" value="printdata"/>
<div id="showresult"></div>
```

Comment: You'd better use CSS classes switching by JavaScript, not particular styles.

Comment: Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? What action takes place at `tr` click ? , at `input type="button"` click ? , what is expected to display at `#showresult` ?

Comment: Your question isn't clear about your expected output.

Comment: @guest271314, Darshan Patel,  Say i have two rows, The textbox will be hidden and the label will be available as a display  when a user click on a selected row the label should be hidden and the text box should be visible and after that if the user clicks on the button then the data or the clicked row textbox value should be printed `#showresult`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Say i have two rows, The textbox will be hidden and the label will be
>   available as a display when a user click on a selected row the label
>   should be hidden and the text box should be visible and after that if
>   the user clicks on the button then the data or the clicked row textbox
>   value should be printed `#showresult`

Try utilizing `.toggle()` to display , not display `label` , `input` elements within `tr` clicked element ; create variable `index` corresponding to `tr` element clicked ; at click of `#printdata` , iterate 
`tr` at `index` using `.each()` , create an object having property of `label` , value of `input` , set `#showresult` `html` to created object

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var index = null;
  $("tr").click(function() {
    $("input, label", this).toggle();
    index = $(this).index("tr");
  });
  $("input[type=button]").click(function() {
    var obj = {};
    var elems = $("tr").eq(index).find("label, input");
    elems.each(function(i, el) {
      if ($(el).is("label")) {
        obj[el.textContent] = elems[i + 1].value
      }
    });
    $("#showresult").html("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2) + "</pre>")
  })
});
```

```css
tr td input {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1" cellspacing="1" width="100%" id="table1">
  <tbody>
    <tr style="background:transparent">
      <th>Column1</th>
      <th>Column2</th>
      <th>Column3</th>
      <th>Column4</th>
      <th>Column5</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>data1</label>
        <input type="text" value="1" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data2</label>
        <input type="text" value="2" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data3</label>
        <input type="text" value="3" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data4</label>
        <input type="text" value="4" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data5</label>
        <input type="text" value="5" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>data6</label>
        <input type="text" value="6" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data7</label>
        <input type="text" value="7" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data8</label>
        <input type="text" value="8" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data9</label>
        <input type="text" value="9" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>data10</label>
        <input type="text" value="10" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="button" value="printdata" />
<div id="showresult"></div>
```